# Change C# System.Numerics.Vector to mutable?

Tags: c#, vectorization, immutable-collections, system.numerics

I am considering using `System.Numerics.Vector` in my C# project which involves lots of math computations. The main thing this package attracts me is the hardware accelerated feature. However, the data structure is said to be immutable whereas in my scenario, there will be frequent updates on several vectors. I found that there is nothing like the `Builder` in `System.Collection.Immutable` package, so the only way I can come up with is to produce a new vector each time I need to change it, which is very time-consuming.

Any idea how should I deal with this? Or are there any other packages that can do fast vector math in C#?

Comment: The vector types are structs, I seriously doubt you can create a mutable version of it without lots of other performance problems. Have you verified that a bottleneck *is* that you're creating lots of these values, or do you *assume* that this is the case?

Comment: Are you sure creation of those `Vector`s is that slow? Did you measure it to be a bottleneck?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I am only worrying about this. I have done simple profiling on initializing the vectors from arrays and found that it takes roughly the same amount of time as Vector.Dot. And in my case, every several millisecond, I will update several vectors...so yes, this just an assumption

Comment: @slawekwin I made a simple profiling and elaborate a bit on my case in the last comment

Comment: Also, you can't change those existing types, so if you want to reuse all the extra classes and methods that deal with those vectors, you need to keep the types as they are.

Comment: FYI, initialize a vector of 400 elements from an array takes about 0.289 nanosecond and dot two vectors of 400 elements takes about 0.305 ns. And an extreme case is that every 1 millisecond, I need to update all the elements in vector `a` and `b` and then do multiplication and dot and some other computations using them.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen actually this is a design and I am re-writing some old project from scratch...

Comment: Hmm, if you can move 400 vectors in a single processor clock cycle then you are doing something very wrong, such hardware does not exist.  The type is notoriously poorly understood, it does have a lousy name.  Something like SimdRegister would have been better.  Also very hard to deal with it storing a fixed number of values that depend on the processor.  If you want somebody to look at your code then you have to post it.

Comment: @HansPassant the newest .NET framework support simd but you still think my profilling has some problems?